# Equation of a flying kite

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, string

My question is the following:

*What is the shape of the rope which holds a kite flying?* (Steady state.)

I am not a physicist (I am a mathematician), so I can not work the physics part of the question.

My guess is that it should be the same as catenary (hyperbolic cosine)

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/51485/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Your guess is correct

Comment: ""it should be the same as catenary (hyperbolic cosine) "" It is not the same, it is a catenary, but only in math. In physics You have to know the drag of the wind on every piece of the rope. Because this drag is a rather nonlinear function of wind velocity, things are complicated.

Comment: @Georg but you *know* that in physics, all ropes are massless, frictionless, 1-dimensional objects. :-) . Tho' in this case I guess we have to give it mass (so the catenary doesn't collapse to a line segment), but let's keep it frictionless and inextensible.

Answer (score 2):

The catenary shape between two points with coordinates $A=(0,0)$ and $B=(S,h)$ is

$$ y(x) = y_C + a \left( \cosh \left( \frac{x-x_C}{a} \right)-1 \right) $$

where

$$ \begin{gather}  a  = \frac{H}{w} &  \mbox{Catenary Constant} \\
H : &  \mbox{Horizontal Tension} \\
w : &  \mbox{Weight per Unit Length} \\
x_C  = \frac{S}{2} + a \sinh \left( \frac{h \exp(\eta)}{a (1-\exp(2\eta))} \right) &  \mbox{Lowest Point x coordinate} \\
y_C  = -a \left( \cosh\left( -\frac{x_C}{a}\right)-1\right) &  \mbox{Lowest Point y coordinate} \\
\eta  = \frac{S}{2 a} &  \mbox{strain factor}
\end{gather} $$

The results look like this:
[image: Catenary]

Comment: I've been (idly) wondering about an extension of these solutions:  what is the value of  $h$  ( the relative height of the second anchor point) at which the catenary's lowest point equals $h$ -- now all I have to do is find the extrema of $y_C$

Comment: Yes, that is the tower uplift condition and it occurs when $x_c=0$ or $x_c=S$ depending on the side it happens. You can solve for it and find the constant $a$ that this happens for (numerically), or $h$ itself. The solution I got was $$ h = \pm a \left(\cosh\left(\frac{S}{a}\right)-1\right) $$