# The hanging chain problem (catenary), numerically

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, computational-physics

I am supossed to solve the hanging chain in constant homogeneus gravity field:

[image]

The chain of length $L_0$ is divided into $N$ parts which are homogenous with length $l$ and mass $m$ and connected by ideal joints. I am supposed to study the curve with different $N$ and $l$. It´s always true that $Nl=L_0=const.$ I´ve seen the analytical solution but I am supposed to do it numerically and I am supposed to get a set of inhomogenous equations a then solve them numerically. But I dont know how to get the equations. According to the task I am supposed to get a set of normal equations not differential equations. Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you provide the analytical solution form start to end? You may do out HW in steps: 1. Define the problem, 2. Write appropriate equations. 3. Apply numerical methods. 4. Interpret the results.

Comment: This is a standard problem which is solved in many places on the internet. eg Googling your question I found [this](http://home2.fvcc.edu/~dhicketh/DiffEqns/Spring11projects/Torrey_Seward_Kirk_Gordon/1Project/Kirk&ToreysDifEQ.pdf) as #4.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/421957/why-is-the-shape-of-a-hanging-chain-not-a-v

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The catenary shape equation is $$ y(x) = y_C + a \left( \cosh \left( \frac{x-x_C}{a} \right) -1 \right) $$ where $(x_C,y_C)$ is the coordinate of the lowest point and $a$ is the so called catenary constant. At the supports the forces on the horizontal direction are $H$ and the unit weight of the cable is $w = \rho g A$ making the catenary constant $$a = \frac{H}{w} $$

Use the above to find the end-points of each segment. For a segment spanning between $x_1$ and $x_2$ in the horizontal direction with length $\ell$ and angle orientation $\theta$ the following is true

$$ \begin{align} 
  x_2 = x_1 + \ell \cos \theta \\ 
  y_2 = y_1 + \ell \sin \theta 
\end{align} $$

Now for the balance of forces. The weight of each segment is $W = w \ell$ and the force equations

$$ \begin{align} 
  (T + \Delta T) \cos \left( \theta + \Delta \theta\right) -  T \cos \left( \theta \right) & = 0 \\
  (T + \Delta T) \sin \left( \theta + \Delta \theta\right) -  T \sin \left( \theta \right) - w \ell & = 0
\end{align} $$

where $T$ and $\theta$ is the tension and angle on the left side of the segment and $T+\Delta T$ and $\theta + \Delta \theta$ the tension and angle on the right side.

This means that each segment recursively changes the tension and angle by

$$ \begin{align} 
  \Delta T & = \sqrt{T^2+w^2 \ell^2+2 T w \ell \sin \theta}-T \\
  \Delta \theta & = \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{\cos \theta}{\sin\theta + \frac{T}{w \ell} } \right)
\end{align} $$

You can check the results against the analytical form of the tension and angle 
$$ \begin{align} 
  T &= H \cosh\left( \frac{x-x_C}{a} \right) \\
  \theta &= \sinh\left( \frac{x-x_C}{a} \right) 
\end{align} $$

Answer (score 1):

Just first shot:

You may start with formula for steady state: $$\sum \mathbf F_i=0$$ where $\mathbf F_i$ are forces applied to the body under scope.

In our case there are forces between neighbours and gravity. Let's denote:

- $\mathbf F_{i+}$ the force applied to $i$-th "free" joint from the right neighbour,
- $\mathbf F_{i-}$ the force applied to $i$-th joint from the left neighbour,
- $\mathbf G_{i}$ the gravitational force applied to $i$-th joint.

For every joint equation $\mathbf F_{i+}+\mathbf F_{i-}+\mathbf G_{i}=\mathbf 0$ must be valid.

Decompose the vectors to their parts and solve for all $i$:
$$F_{xi+}+F_{xi-}=0\\F_{yi+}+F_{yi-}+G_y=0$$

You may look for the angles of each massless rod and when you know their lengths and angles you can find positions of each joint.