# Tension in Common Catenary

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram, string, statics

I was reading the intrinsic equation of common catenary , where the author assumes tension in the catenary and proceeds.

Why does a freely hanging rope with uniform mass per unit length has tension ? This is contradictory to the fact we use in solving problems in mechanics i.e. when the rope becomes slack, we take the tension in the rope to be zero .

[image]

Comment: _catenary_ is the correct spelling.

Comment: corrected , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The catenary is the shape of a self-supporting cable *with mass*. Typically in mechanics ropes are massless and their shape when in not carrying tension is undefined, and when carrying tension are just straight lines.

But for a rope/chain/cable that has a defined mass per length, the shape must curve because the tension on the ends of each segment must balance out the weight of the segment in-between.

[image: fig]

Take any segment, and the weight $W$ must be counter-balanced by the vertical support loads $V_1$ and $V_2$. In addition, the combined tension on the left $\sqrt{H^2+V_1^2}$ must be tangent to the shape, and similarly for the combined tension on the right.

> See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/304445/the-hanging-chain-problem-catenary-numerically/304484#304484) for the development of the equations.

Those are the necessary conditions to define the shape of the catenary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

In simple mechanics problems we assume that a string is massless. In the catenary the chain has mass.

Comment: Let us say we have a rope hanging between two ends of a pole . Half of the rope has W mass per unit length and the other half is massless . Both the parts are symmetrical . Will there be tension in the massless part of the rope ?

Comment: Yes, and that massless part will be straight, with no sag.