# Tension In A Massive Rope

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, equilibrium, string

My book says :**the horizontal component of the tension in a massive rope is constant.**

---

It does not seem intuitive to me as I don't think that the above approximation (I guess) is possible.I don't know though

---

Can anyone help me out with this as I am just not getting it.

---

Any help and hints are appreciated .

Comment: is this necessary in some context? i.e. constant in such and such a situation? I cannot believe it is *always* constant, like a universal constant.

Comment: @rpfphysics  If you can tell me about any case if this is possible

Comment: i don't understand the question basically. The tension in a rope is constant if it is in equilibirum.

Comment: Even I am not getting it..

Comment: related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/131403

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any section of the rope can be considered as a Free Body. If the section is not accelerating then the horizontal and vertical components of force on it are balanced.

If there are no forces external to the rope acting horizontally on the section, then the forces from the rope at the left and right (ie tension) must be equal. If the rope has mass then there is an external force acting vertically, so the forces on the section from above and below will differ by the weight of the section of rope.

The horizontal component of tension is not constant if the rope is accelerating horizontally - eg oscillating or rotating.